# Change how a class instance appears in Java debugger

Tags: java, debugging

Is there a way to change how a class appears in the Java debugger?

The use case is as follows, I have a `Builder` type which has `Machine` child, which on its turn contains an array of `Component`s, which on its end contains a `String` inside.

This means that if I want to know if my builder contains a specific component, in the debugger, I have to open the builder, than open the machine, than open the array, than open every index individually, and then open every component inside of it.

Is there a way to change how for example my component class is represented in the debugger? Make it appear as for example `Component("Hello") #412` instead of `#412`, as it does now?

Comment: Since you have an array of components, which component do you want the debugger to show? And which debugger are you using?

Comment: No guarantees, but overriding `toString()` on your `Component` class might help.

Comment: @Sweeper In Netbeans, next to every array index (e.g `[15]` it shows the reference at that location (e.g. `#512`). This requires me to open two levels of indirection for every array element. The goal is to have it say something along the lines of `[15] Component("Hello") #512` instead.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Doing that does not change the `Value` column in the debugger. That said, it does work with a watch expression calling `toString`, but that is not very useful for arrays. 

It doesn't appear to be impossible, built-in types like `ArrayList` override their representation with something along the lines as `"size=129"`.